# Recording audio through 3.5mm jack on a Mac

Tags: audio, input

I connect my gaming headset to a little mixamp. The mixamp has a raw audio 3.5 mm output jack. I want to use a 3.5mm male to male aux chord to record the audio output from the mixamp on my Mac (my voice, game chat, etc.).

Unfortunately, my iMac and MacBook do not detect the mixamp as a sound input. Rather, it seems they are using the aux chord as an output.

My question is: If I replace my aux chord for a 4-pole aux chord, will my Mac recognize the mixamp as an audio input?

For reference, I am using the Astro A40 TR headset + Mixamp Pro. The Mixamp has an output Jack that says "stream" and it's supposed to be a raw audio output (everything that goes into the mixamp may come out from there, including my voice, game chat, game sound, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've found out, most 3.5 mm cables won't work.

> If I replace my aux chord for a 4-pole aux chord, will my Mac recognize the mixamp as an audio input?

If you use the correct cable, yes. There are [2 pinouts](https://www.cablechick.com.au/blog/understanding-trrs-and-audio-jacks/) for 4-pole 3.5mm jacks, you need the Apple variant:

[image]

You may have issues with level or impedance matching (which manifest as distorted audio), although the Apple mic input accepts quite a wide range of inputs.
The input is mono.